# What it is the right command to query the application thread that have terminated but waiting to be joined?

Tags: linux, shell

I've been looking without success what it is the way to find out how many threads have terminated and waiting to be join on a running application.

I will called them zombies threads. I thought we could do it with ps, htop or top. But they only shown active threads. They disappear from the list once the thread function returns.

The only clue I I have seen to detect that "tread leak" is the Virtual memory usage as a thread stack memory is assigned on creation and it is not freed until the thread is properly joined. But that it is a complicated way to detect this leak on a production enviroment.

I'm wondering if there is a better way that show the list of all threads created by an application including the ones waiting to be joined.

Comment: If they're not shown in programs like `top`, I suspect the threading library has the data, not the OS.

Comment: You can use `truss` to see all system calls made by the parent process.  You will then see the created and killed threads.

Comment: Barmar -- According to the documentation, the tid cannot be reused until the thread has been joined. tid should be done on the kernel side, right? So not sure who the kernel can rely on library to achieve that.

Comment: @Nic3500 -- this means that I need to instrument the process before starting it. I'm looking for a way that allows to inspect a system in production. Something similar to run ps for running threads and processes. Or a counter in /proc/self/<some_file> that has counts all the tid's in used by the applications, or similar.